# Open Solaris won't boot after bad shutdown

Tags: solaris, shutdown

Open Solaris does not boot after powering off w/o shutting down. My manual says that bad shut downs can corrupt files and prevent booting.

When I try to boot from the GRUB the loading icon on Gnome keeps circulating, even after several hours. By hitting <kbd>esc</kbd> I can bring up a command line. `beadm list -a` lists opensolaris in root along with several snapshots. I tried creating a new BE but without luck

I plan to try to make  a new BE from a snapshot, but I am not hopeful.

Any ideas to start boot?

Comment: can you be more specific, hane you access to console ? what is displayed ?

Comment: When I try to boot from the GRUB the loading icon on Gnome keeps circulating, even after several hours. By hitting esc I can bring up a command line. beadm list -a lists opensolaris in root along with several snapshots. I tried creating a new BE but, no luck. I am about to see if I can crate a BE from a snapshot, but I am not hopeful.